# Probability of card sequence of 1,2,3

Tags: probability

If I have $3$ cards numbered $1$,$2$ and $3$ and pick them randomly replacing the picked card for the next pick.

**My Attempt**: I understand the odds of picking each card is $\frac{1}{3}$.  The odds of picking that same card twice is $\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3}$ and so on.  What is the possibility of randomly picking the sequence of $1$, then $2$, and $3$?  It seems it has to be more complicated than $\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{3}$.  If it is then odds of repeating the exact same sequence of $1$,$2$ and $3$?  Thanks, under educated:)

Comment: The prob of picking 1, then 2, then 3 is just $\frac{1}{27}$. The prob of doing that twice is $\frac{1}{27^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

You are right about the probability of picking the sequence of $1,2,3$. It is $\frac13\times\frac13\times\frac13=\frac{1}{27}$
And due to replacement, the probability of picking the same number is equal to picking a different number, so no matter what sequence you pick, the probability will always be $\frac{1}{27}$ as long as you are picking three cards.
Remember when order matters, and with replacement, you use permutations: $n^{r}$

Answer (score 0):

The number of possible sequences of three picks is $3 \times 3 \times 3$, for example $1 1 1, 1 2 1, 1 2 3, 3 2 3$ and so on.
So the odds of randomly picking the sequence $1, 2, 3$ is $\frac{1}{27}$.